# Adding a sub layer or UIView as subview to the top using z-order of UIButton still goes behind the view or look transparent

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I have a `UIButton` and i want to add a circle badge on top of it, here is how it looks.

```
public func addCircleBadge(_ width: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {
        let bounds = self.mybtn.bounds
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        let radius = width / 2
        layer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: bounds.width - (radius + 2.0), y: bounds.minY - (radius-2.0), width: width, height: width), cornerRadius: radius).cgPath
        layer.fillColor = color.cgColor
        layer.zPosition = 999
        layer.name = "circleBadge"
        self.mybtn.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }
```

and in `viewDidLoad()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mybtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    mybtn.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
    mybtn.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    mybtn.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    addCircleBadge(20, color: UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(1.0))
}
```

but this layer is looking transparent, so the button area is visible, i want to have an opaque layer on top of button. can it be done through layer or do i need to add a different view and place both button and this separate `UIView` in a common view

[image: button with ca layer]

Comment: You aren't showing all relevant lines of code.

Comment: `UIbutton` is in storyboard and other than that i have added a border and nothing else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you set `borderWidth` and `borderColor` for `button.layer`. 
This `button.layer` hosts all other sublayer that you add to them that's why your border is always on the top.

So you can use additional view for drawing the circle or...
Just remove setting `borderWidth` and `borderColor` for `button.layer` and add another sublayer that will cover your border.

For example:

```
    func addBorder(borderWidth: CGFloat = 1.0, borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.blue) {
        let layer = CALayer()
        let frame = self.mybtn.frame
        layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height)
        layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        self.mybtn.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }
```

and in ViewDidLoad:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addBorder()
        addCircleBadge(20, color: UIColor.red)
    }
```

Also one update for `addCircleBadge`

```
    public func addCircleBadge(_ width: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {
        ...

        self.mybtn.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 0)
    }
```